# Kubernetes - Ingress on docker driver - minikube 1.16

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm trying to setup ingress on docker driver for minikube 1.16 on windows 10 home (build 19042).
Ingress on docker driver wasn't supported before but it is now on minikube 1.16:
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/9761

I've been trying something by myself but i got `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when connecting to the ingress at `127.0.0.1` OR `kubernetes.docker.internal`

Steps:

1. minikube start
2. minikube addons enable ingress
3. create deployment
4. create ClusterIP
5. Ingress config

Here is my configuration:

```
#cluster ip service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: web
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000

# not posting deployment code because it's not relevant, but there is a deployment with selector 'component:web' and it's exposing port 3000.


#ingress service
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

I have dns redirect in hosts file.

I've also tried "minikube tunnel" on another terminal but no luck either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your ingress object definition under `rules` field:

```yaml
  rules:
    - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
    - http:
        paths:
```

The exact problem is the `-` sing in front the `http` which makes the `host` and `http` separate arrays.

Take a look how your converter yaml looks like in json:

```json
{
  "spec": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "host": "kubernetes.docker.internal"
      },
      {
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "path": "/?(.*)",
              "pathType": "Prefix",
              "backend": {
---
```

This is how annotations looks like with your ingress definition.

```yaml
spec:
  rules:
    - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
```

And now notice how this yaml converted to json looks like:

```json
{
  "spec": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "host": "kubernetes.docker.internal",
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "path": "/?(.*)",
              "pathType": "Prefix",
              "backend": {
---
```

You can easily visualize this even better using [yaml-viewer](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-viewer)

Comment: I've tried this solution, however the same result. You were right about the wrong indentation and the dash, but I still get  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Maybe the ingress is still not fully supported for docker drivers?

Comment: Can you describe to me which exactly address are you trying to reach? In the question you've mentioned localhost, but ingress should be reachable at minikube's ip address. What ip address appears in ingress when you do  `kubectl get ingress` ?

Comment: I've tried to reach it on the minikube ip as well but no luck. I've read in their GitHub somewhere that you have to do "minikube tunnel" first then connect to 127.0.0.1 for the docker driver

Comment: Which version of minikube are you using? Perhaps minikube update might help with it. This is still not well documented. For some people changing driver appears to be working.

Comment: yeah, i agree this is still not documented well, i assume this is a completely new feature. Im using 1.17.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this would not work not when your ingress is corrected and ingress addon is supported. Indeed there is mention on the PR that minikube tunnel is needed to access ingress. I would encourage you to open github issue and see what dev can say about this.

Comment: I did yesterday. Thanks for your help - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10245

Comment: Would you mind testing this with different driver to see if this is not related to that?

Comment: i'm on windows home so Hyper-V  is unavailable for me, i will try with the virtualbox

Comment: you can try this as a workaround `kubectl -n kube-system port-forward pod/<ingress nginx pod name> --address 0.0.0.0 80:80 443:443` . I have also replied to your ticket in github